# Problem with svg export in illustrator. A kind of antialiasing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, antialiasing

1. [illustration on edition mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeX3c.png)
2. [illustration on export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3vJj.png)

My problem is a kind of antialiasing... On my workspace i have no problem but on export i have white borders around shapes.

I try to deactivate antialiasing but nothing happend. I try many things.

Please help.

Comment: It rather looks like there was some transparency flattening applied e.g exporting to pdf<5 like X1a (no transparency support).

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem on my test file. Probably the problem depends on what your ai file looks inside (could you provide the ai file?) and the parameters you're using for svg export (it makes sense to show them).